# How can I post a google spreedsheet value on a website?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a fan site for the online game runescape. I'm making some calculator for the game using google spreedsheets and I wanted to know how could I display a specific value from the sheet on my site in the easiest possible way.

Here is a little more information for those who are interested. The spreed sheet contains values from a runescape data base that displays in game value of items. I had to extract theses values from the runescape.com website into the google spreedsheet to do the calculations I wanted to perform, and now I want to post my results on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to store the information in a database instead of a Google spreadsheet if you'd like to make the site be dynamic (i.e., the values are not static). The actual language here (for example `javascript`) doesn't matter so much enabling your web application to have easy/persistent access to a data store.

Comment: only problem is i don't know how to "rip" the data I want off the runescape website's tables without using google spreedsheet. How would I pull these values?:

http://itemdb-rs.runescape.com/results.ws?query=clean

Comment: I would use something like `curl` to download the HTML, then parse it using something like `lxml` (which is for python)

Comment: thanks for your help david but that might be a bit to advance for me. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Looking back now at this, my approach was terrible. I should of just used good old fashion Javascript and some libraries and/or a DB.